# How to add an element to queue in UiPath studio?

Tags: automation, ui-automation, uipath, rpa

While exploring the Automation tool UiPath Studio, I tried to add an element to queue. But while executing, it was showing up some error like this: 'Queues service url is not defined. Make sure the robot is connected to UiPath server'.

I searched for a solution and I found that I had to uncomment a few lines in UiRobot.exe config file(I have pasted those lines below). Does anyone know how to resolve this issue ? Appreciate your responses. Thank you :)

UiRobot.exe uncommented lines:

```
    <endpoint name="RestEndpoint" address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/UiPath/service/agent" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebHttpBinding_IRemoteContract" contract="UiPath.Models.IUiPathRemoteContract" behaviorConfiguration="RestEndpointBehaviour" />
    <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8080/UiPath/service/agent/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Error that pops up while executing this use case:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The URL used for queues in the Orchestrator and the URL in Config file should match. Mismatch in the URL might be the reason as well.